# Export GitHub impact graph to image

Tags: github

I really like GitHub's [impact graph about my Open Source project](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/graphs/impact). I would like to include it in a presentation, so I would like to download it as an image.

How to export this graph to an image?

Anything smarter than taking hundreds of screenshots and assembling them?

That's the lame method I used last year to produce the image below (out-of-date):

[image: image from last year]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need the textual labels (which are drawn as `<p>` overlays), you could just right-click the graph in Firefox and choose "Save Image As..." (It's a `<canvas>` element and Chrome doesn't yet offer a save option for those).

If you do need the date labels, I'd suggest looking for a Firefox screenshot extension capable of grabbing a complete screenshot of a scrolling sub-element in one go. (I know they exist for `<iframe>` elements, so being able to do it for a scrolled `<div>` isn't outside the realm of possibility)

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I needed. Strange "Save as Image" did not show on Chrome.

Comment: "Save As Image" doesn't show on Chrome because `<canvas>` isn't `<img>` and it takes extra code (which they may not yet have written) to generate a PNG from a raw grid of pixel data rather than pulling an already existing one from the cache.